# prev - next dynamic content display with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors, slider

I am trying to make prev - next sliding between content on a page. I have the following markup:

```
<div class="right">
     <a href="javascript:;" class="light-button" id="previous-button">Previous</a>
     <a href="javascript:;" class="light-button" id="next-button">Next</a>
 </div>
 <?php foreach ($chapters as $chapter) : ?>
 <div id="chapters-container-<?php echo $chapter->id; ?>" style="display: none">
     <div class="left">
         <h1 class="hmc"><?php echo $chapter->title; ?></h1>
     </div>
     <ul class="attachments scroll-pane">
     <?php foreach ($chapter->files as $file) : ?>
     <!--video zone-->
         <?php if ($file->extension == '.mpeg') : ?>
         <li class="wide">
             <img src="" />
             <span class="duration hmc"><?php $file->duration; ?></span>
             <h1 class="hmc">The title is a title</h1>

         </li>
         <?php endif; ?>                              
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Basically I generate some content dynamically with PHP. I have wrapped each content generated in a div and I do not display it only with jQuery.
Now I tried doing something like:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a#next-button', function(){
    $('#chapters-container-').next();
});
```

but ofc it is not working as I want it. How can I make the content change when i toggle between prev and next button based on the markup I am generating.

Comment: The next button needs to have some type of attached functionality to it. Are you using jQuery Tools? Are you creating a custom next function? Are you toggling the LI?

Comment: no.i already get the content with ajax and generate it ...i just need to slide between the divs generated

Comment: Did you try to add a class with "display: none" to each item to hide them. a class to select the current visible one and then using next()/prev()/css() to change them?

Comment: no i did not try to do it that way yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you don't get what

```
$('#chapters-container-').next();
```

does. This, according to the documentation,

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

so you are just selecting the next element after the element with id = chapters-container-

Youy should do something like:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a#next-button', function(){ 
  var visisbleContainer = $('div[id^=chapters-container-]:visible');
  visisbleContainer.next().show();
  visisbleContainer.hide(); 
});
```

Comment: i need the entire div `<div id="chapters-container-<?php echo $chapter->id; ?>" style="display: none">` to move around

Comment: still not working...firebug shows that it breaks after `var visisbleContainer = $('div[id^=chapters-container-]:visisble');
` I will try to debug it now..you had a typo..but it's still not working as expected

Comment: @Mythriel i had a typo. i need to see the generated markup, because probably visisbleContainer.next() is not ok. can you post the generated markup on jsfiddle?

Comment: no need anymore...i figure it out ... the visibleContainer was the last div with that id on the page and that is why it did not work properly

Answer (score 0):

when user clicks on next button get the visible div( chapter ) id attribute.You would receive the chapter id add 1 to this chapter id and generate another string such as chapters-container-2.

Now hide the current div and show the div of the generated string i.e $('#'+ newstring).show()